# PowerShell - &string Collision with Existing Alias

Tags: powershell

code:

```
function start() {
  # do something
}

&"start"
```

How would keep & from finding the Start-Process alias first? Is there a way of removing the start alias for the lifetime of my script? Changing the name of the function is not an option.

Comment: matthewg and campbell.rw how would you modify the techniques you mention if you wanted to add a single parameter getting passed?

Comment: just add the parameter to the end of the call after the call operator and function, e.g. `&(gi function:\start) 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specifically tell it you want to call the function, and not an alias.

```
function start() {
  # do something
  Write-Output "It Worked"
}

&(gi function:\start)
```

Any parameters can just be tacked on to the end of the call, as usual.

```
function start() {
    Param(
        [int] $toout
    )
  # do something
  Write-Output "It Worked: $($toout + 5): See!"
}

&(gi function:\start) 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Put:

```
Remove-Item alias:\start -Force
```

at the top of the script to remove it for the run, or add it to the system `profile.ps1` to remove it permanently (every time powershell starts)

Answer (score 2):

This also works, similar to the first answer:

```
function start(){
    Write-Host "FOO"
}

&(get-command -CommandType Function -Name start)
```